# First UITextView text animation get skipped when cascading animations swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to cascade animations but the first gets partially skipped. I've seen other posts with same problem, but when applying the solutions offered it doesn't solve my problem. It actually behaves strangely. The animations basically just animate the alpha of 7 different `UIImageView` showing them one after the other while changing the text of a `UITextView`.
In the first animation the correct text gets displayed just briefly and then it changes to the next one while the correct image is still shown. 
From now on is just displaying on text ahead.. So animations do work in cascade as expected.. they just do it partially..
Also in the sixth animation ( a longer text ) half of it gets displayed during current animation, then the other half gets briefly displayed before the text in seventh animation.
Is there a problem with animating `UITextView`'s text? If so, what's the proper way to change displayed text over time?
I though it could have to do with the fact that the `UITextView` text is a `NSLocalizedString`, but changing it to common `String` didn't make a difference (I know..I just start trying all kind of things when in trouble..)
As always many thanks for your time and help.
This is the inglorious code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 3, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            print("1 hintScheduler")
            self.hintTextView.text = NSLocalizedString("hintScheduler", comment: "") // this text gets displayed just for an instant and then skipped
            self.hintImage1.alpha = 1
            self.hintTextView.alpha = 1


                }, completion: { (true)  in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 3, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                print("2 hintShop")
                self.hintTextView.text = NSLocalizedString("hintShop", comment: "")
                self.hintImage1.alpha = 0
                self.hintImage2.alpha = 1


            }, completion: { (true) in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 3, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                    print("3 hintOrders")
                    self.hintTextView.text = NSLocalizedString("hintOrders", comment: "")
                    self.hintImage2.alpha = 0
                    self.hintImage3.alpha = 1

                }, completion: { (true) in
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 3, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                        print("4 hintBookings")
                        self.hintTextView.text = NSLocalizedString("hintBookings", comment: "")
                        self.hintImage3.alpha = 0
                        self.hintImage4.alpha = 1

                    }, completion: { (true) in
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 3, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                            print("5 hintRoutes")
                            self.hintTextView.text = NSLocalizedString("hintRoutes", comment: "")
                            self.hintImage4.alpha = 0
                            self.hintImage5.alpha = 1

                        }, completion: { (true) in
                            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 3, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                                print("6 hintSpeedo")
                                self.hintTextView.text = NSLocalizedString("hintSpeedo", comment: "") // here text gets truncated until the next aniimation starts
                                self.hintImage5.alpha = 0
                                self.hintImage6.alpha = 1

                            }, completion: { (true) in
                                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 3, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                                    print("7 hintSettings")
                                    self.hintTextView.text = "settings"//NSLocalizedString("hintSettings", comment: "")
                                    self.hintImage6.alpha = 0
                                    self.hintImage7.alpha = 1

                                }, completion: { (true) in
                                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 3, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                                        print("closing")
                                        self.hintImage7.alpha = 0
                                        self.hintTextView.alpha = 0
                                    }, completion: { (true) in
                                        print("finished")
                                    })
                                })
                            })
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        })
```

UPDATE: 
A working ( dough not very image/text synchronised ) animation would be to nest every passage image -> text -> image2 -> text2...but that is a nonsense, as for my 8 steps animation that means a 15 levels nesting...I have it working..but I would obviously avoid that..
So I'm trying `animateKeyframes` and as far as I understood code should be correct..but.. the result is just the same.. actually worse..displayed text is always the last one to display..dough prints are correct.
I separated images and text into different keyframes but the result is the same.. if I comment out the images keyframes, text doesn't even show..
I really think it has to do with textview text animation not being possible. Do you successfully animate it?

```
let duration = 8.0;
        let relativeDuration = 1.0/8;

        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: .overrideInheritedOptions, animations: {


//            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0 * relativeDuration, relativeDuration: relativeDuration, animations: {
//                print("1 hintScheduler")
//                self.hintImage1.alpha = 1
//                self.hintTextView.alpha = 1
//            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0 * relativeDuration, relativeDuration: relativeDuration, animations: {
                print("1 hintScheduler")
                self.hintTextView.text = NSLocalizedString("hintScheduler", comment: "")
            })


//            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: relativeDuration, relativeDuration: relativeDuration, animations: {
//                print("2 hintShop")
//                self.hintImage1.alpha = 0
//                self.hintImage2.alpha = 1
//            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: relativeDuration, relativeDuration: relativeDuration, animations: {
                print("2 hintShop")
                self.hintTextView.text = NSLocalizedString("hintShop", comment: "")
            })


//            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 2 * relativeDuration, relativeDuration: relativeDuration, animations: {
//                print("3 hintOrders")
//                self.hintImage2.alpha = 0
//                self.hintImage3.alpha = 1
//            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 2 * relativeDuration, relativeDuration: relativeDuration, animations: {
                print("3 hintOrders")
                self.hintTextView.text = NSLocalizedString("hintOrders", comment: "")
            })


//            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 3 * relativeDuration, relativeDuration: relativeDuration, animations: {
//                print("4 hintBookings")
//                self.hintImage3.alpha = 0
//                self.hintImage4.alpha = 1
//            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 3 * relativeDuration, relativeDuration: relativeDuration, animations: {
                print("4 hintBookings")
                self.hintTextView.text = NSLocalizedString("hintBookings", comment: "")
            })


//            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 4 * relativeDuration, relativeDuration: relativeDuration, animations: {
//                print("5 hintRoutes")
//                self.hintImage4.alpha = 0
//                self.hintImage5.alpha = 1
//            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 4 * relativeDuration, relativeDuration: relativeDuration, animations: {
                print("5 hintRoutes")
                self.hintTextView.text = NSLocalizedString("hintRoutes", comment: "")
            })


//            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 5 * relativeDuration, relativeDuration: relativeDuration, animations: {
//                print("6 hintSpeedo")
//                self.hintImage5.alpha = 0
//                self.hintImage6.alpha = 1
//            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 5 * relativeDuration, relativeDuration: relativeDuration, animations: {
                print("6 hintSpeedo")
                self.hintTextView.text = NSLocalizedString("hintSpeedo", comment: "")
            })

//
//            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 6 * relativeDuration, relativeDuration: relativeDuration, animations: {
//                print("7 hintSettings")
//                self.hintImage6.alpha = 0
//                self.hintImage7.alpha = 1
//            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 6 * relativeDuration, relativeDuration: relativeDuration, animations: {
                print("7 hintSettings")
                self.hintTextView.text = NSLocalizedString("hintSettings", comment: "")
            })


//            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 7 * relativeDuration, relativeDuration: relativeDuration, animations: {
//                print("closing")
//                self.hintImage7.alpha = 0
//                self.hintTextView.alpha = 0
//            })
        }) { (true) in
            print("k animation finished")
        }
```

Comment: did you try this with animateKeyframes instead of trying to nest them like you're doing?

Comment: @Loxx No, I haven't tried it as I never used it. I actually solved it by separating the animations. 1st animation takes car of the alpha, then on completion a new animation only for text swapping is triggered with 0 delay. It works now as I wanted.
Only thing I have to understand is why text gets weirdly animated when in the same animation with alphas.

Comment: @Loxx Anyway this mega nesting is having a side effect of a little lag between image and text switching, due by the duration of the image animation.
I'll have to dig into `animateKeyframes`as this lag is quite annoying and lowering the animation duration makes it scatty.. 
Thanks for the tip.